# How to apply relationship with two id's in laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.3

So I have a model called `data_storage` and another model `entity_states`

I have to fetch the record from `data_storage` with `entity_states` where entity_state has `data_storage_id` and `state_id`.

How can I use eloquent to achieve this ?.

Or Ill have to use Query builder and use innerJoin?

**Update1**

My Actual Query

```
$this->values['new_leads'] = $data_storages->with('actions','states','sla')->where('wf_id',$wfid)->get();
```

My `data_storage` modal

```
class data_storages extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['layout_id','member_id','company_id','team_id','data','status','wf_id'];



    function actions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ActionDataMaps', 'data_id', 'id' );
    }

    function states()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\workflow_states','id','status');
    }

    function sla()
    {
       //Here I have to get those row from entity_states model where , data_storage_id and state_id 
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Check the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @apokryfos can you suggest what kind of relationship to use , I tried hasOne but it works only with one Id

Comment: First of all you need to understand what relationships you actually have. `data_storage` is a model and `state` is another model. `entity_states` is a pivot table, so you have a many to many between `data_storage` and `states`

Comment: What you are talking about is Many to Many relation between two entities, *Tables*, data_storages and states. If your database schema has another structure, you may have to rethink about its structure again.

Comment: Also, it is better to supply some hints about your schema in the question.

Comment: @SaidbakR Okay i am updating the complete query

Comment: @SaidbakR Can you have a look once again I updated  The query i am trying to do

Comment: I can easily write the Join query using the builder but I really want to learn the RelationSHip of eloquent

Comment: In your `data_storages` model: First: classes names, as convention, should starts with Uppercase and it should be CamelCased . Second `states()` should be `belongsToMany` not `hasOne`.

Comment: @Vikram checkout apokryfos answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the more reasonable way to do it:

```
class DataStorage extends Model { 
     public states() {
         return $this->belongsToMany(State::class,"entity_states");
     }
}

class State extends Model {
     public storages() {
         return $this->belongsToMany(DataStorage::class,"entity_states");
     }
}
```

Then you can eager-load related models via e.g.:

```
$storage = DataStorage::with("states")->first();
$storage->states->first()->column_in_related_state;
```

Or via the state:

```
$state = State::with("storages")->first();
$state->storages->first()->column_in_related_storage;
```

If there are additional columns in the **pivot table** `entity_states` then you can refer to them in the relationship as e.g.:

```
public states() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(State::class)->withPivot("pivot_column");
}
```

Comment: Also, a pivot table should be found.

Comment: Thanks Let em fix the changes

Comment: @apokryfos umm in my data_storage table the state column is called, ```status```

Comment: If you are relating `data_storage` with `state` directly and via `entity_states` that's 2 different kinds of relationships. This code is just for the many to many using the pivot table. The direct one is a one to many and needs to be defined differently (this just raises further questions regarding your design though)

Answer (score 1):

In your model `data_storage` you can define a property / method `entity_states` to get them:

```
class data_storage extends Model
{
    public function entity_states()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\entity_states','data_storage_id')->where('state_id ','=',$this->table());
    }
}
```

Then you can access them in an instance by

```
$entityStatesOfDataStorage = $yourDataStorageInstance->entity_states;
```

See this link:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: hasMany will not work because I have to fetch those entity_states where , data_storage_id and state_id matches

Comment: Sorry, I did not get that in the initial post. Please see my edit. I googled for that, so that code is not tested. But it got several positive feedback. Please let me know, if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

for Query Builder you may use this:

```
DB::table('data_storage')
    ->join('entity_states','data_storage.data_storage_id','=','entity_states.state_id')
    ->get();
```

For your reference [Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries)

Comment: I know this will work , but I was looking for Eloquent answer

Comment: @Vikram sorry my bad. if thats the case then dns_nx's answer is the way.

Comment: no his answer is wrong because the relation is not HasMany